# How can I set a max width on a LinearLayout so that it doesn't stretch in Landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-orientation

My app looks great in portrait mode, but it stretches out in landscape and looks bad.  I know I could make a separate layout for landscape, but I'd rather just set my root element's maximum width so that landscape mode just results in some white space on the sides. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Keeping different layout files is a correct solution but it adds complexity to your project (you'd have to maintain multiple files in case the designer redesigns the view layout).

If all you need is to alter the width of a LinearLayout, you can do the following. Keep one xml file in the layout folder and give it a value of

```
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/width_match_parent_max_200"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

then, in your values-600dp/styles.xml write:

```
<resources>
<style name="width_match_parent_max_200">
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and in your values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="width_match_parent_max_200">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the cleanest solution :) btw it didn't work for me at first due to two things: 1) it should be values-w600dp instead (yours is missing the 'w' character) 2) My device dimension is 320dp x 480dp so I have changed it to values-w320dp with layout_width of 320dp instead and works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The [BoundedViews library](https://github.com/baole/BoundedViews) allows to set boundedWidth/boundedHeight on views even layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: That library is totally awesome, thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution I can think of is to set right and left margins, saved in separate dimen.xml files for portrait and landscape.